# how to use xsl:param value in the xsl:attribute name="width"

Tags: xslt, width

It sounds easy, but none of my "easy" syntax worked:

```
<xsl:param name="length"/>
<xsl:attribute name="width">$length</xsl:attribute>
not
<xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of-select="$length"></xsl:attribute>
```

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: You may want to format your sample code to make it easier to read. Click the "edit" link, highlight your code sample and click the code format button.

Comment: Good question, but you need to format your code (I did it for you this time). +1. See my answer, which offers two solutions and recommends the better of them. :)

Answer (score 8):

> `<xsl:attribute
>   name="width">$length</xsl:attribute>`

This will create an attribute with value the string `$length`. But you want the value of the xsl:param named `$length`.

> `<xsl:attribute
>   name="width"><xsl:value-of-select="$length"></xsl:attribute>`

Here the `<xsl:value-of>` element is not closed -- this makes the XSLT code not well-formed xml.

**Solution**:

Use one of the following:

1. **`<xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="$length"/></xsl:attribute>`**

or

2. **`<someElement width="{$length}"/>`**

**For readability and compactness prefer to use 2. above**, whenever possible.

Comment: I assume you mean xsl:value-of, not xsl:value-of-select? :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't even need `xsl:attribute` here; the simplest way to do this is something like:

```
<someElement width="{$length}" ... >...</someElement>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first alternative fails because variables are not expanded in text nodes. Your second alternative fails because you attempt to call `<xsl:value-of-select="...">`, while the proper syntax is `<xsl:value-of select="..."/>`, as described in the section [Generating Text with xsl:value-of](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of) in the standard. You can fix your code by using

```
<xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="$length"/></xsl:attribute>
```

or, as others have noted, you can use [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates):

```
<someElement width="{$length}" ... >...</someElement>
```