# How to access xsl:param in an attribute of xsl:output?

Tags: xslt

I want to allow the transformer to set a param in my stylesheet to specify how many spaces of indentation are desired.  I have tried all of the suggestions by @Dimitre Novatchev in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664137/288341) to no avail.

```
<xsl:param name="indent" select="0"/><!-- default indent is 0, but transformer could specify a different value -->
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" xalan:indent-amount="{$indent}"/> <!-- This does not work -->
```

How do I assign the value of the `indent` param to the `xalan:indent-amount` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

**It does not appear that Xalan supports attribute value templates for the value of the `xalan:indent-amount` attribute.**

I get a warning message that attribute value templates are not supported in xsl:output in XSLT 1.0. Apparently, they are supported in 1.1 (which should not be used, as it was abandoned by the W3C), but Xalan does not appear to resolve the parameter value in the AVT in that particular attribute.

When I attempt to use the parameter value in an AVT, it returns the error:

```
E For input string "{$indent}"
```

---

**One possible workaround would be to use entities and generate a DTD.** Rather than pass in the indent value as a param, have your XSLT reference a DTD. Generate the DTD file with the indent value that you need and then invoke the XSLT.

For example, create a DTD file like this (assume named "indent.dtd"):

```
<!ENTITY indent "10" >
```

And then reference the DTD in your XSLT like this (assume that indent.dtd is located in the same folder, or you could adjust the path):

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet SYSTEM "indent.dtd">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
               xalan:indent-amount="&indent;"/> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Another workaround would be to generate an XSLT with the desired value for the `xalan:indent-amount` first, and then transform your XML with the newly generated XSLT.**

Answer (score 1):

As @Mads Hansen already said it does not appear that Xalan supports attribute value templates for the value of the `xalan:indent-amount` attribute.

I found that setting the property on the transformer itself does work though.  The nice thing about this is that I don't have to create/modify any files.

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

[Credit goes to @Flynn1179](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102050/288341)