# saxon:indent-spaces attribute is being ignored

Tags: xslt, saxon

In my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752153/how-to-access-xslparam-in-an-attribute-of-xsloutput) I'm trying to pass in a param to my stylesheet so a user can specify the level of indentation desired.  Apparently [Xalan](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan/2.7.1) cannot read the value of a param into its `indent-amount` attribute, so I'm trying with [this version of Saxon-HE](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.5.1-1) instead.

Saxon has the attribute [indent-spaces](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/output-extras/indent-spaces.html) which I am trying to use as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- <xsl:param name="indent-spaces" select="0"/> -->

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" saxon:indent-spaces="10"/><!-- Doesn't matter what I make the value of indent-spaces, the output is always indented 3 spaces -->
```

Why is `indent-spaces` being ignored?

Comment: Which version of Saxon do you use? How do you run the transformation exactly, how is the result tree serialized? And the namespace should be `http://saxon.sf.net/`, not `http://saxon.sf.net`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace should be `xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"` instead of `xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net"`.

Comment: After correcting the namespace I got an error informing me the requested feature requires Saxon-PE :(  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, all Saxon extensions require Saxon-PE or higher.

Second, if you want to control serialization parameters dynamically (e.g. from a stylesheet parameter, you can do this using xsl:result-document:

```
<xsl:result-document indent="yes" saxon:indent-spaces="{$param}">
  ...
</xsl:result-document>
```